# Is there a way to see if a given value exists in a row identified via VLOOKUP and, if so, return the value in another cell in that row?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel data set that summarizes shipping surcharges by tracking number. I have the tracking number in Column A as my Index, but the data is presented such that to the right of the tracking number in Column A, I have pairs of columns that dictate Charge Type and $ Charge to the right of the tracking. The column Headers are generic for the Surcharge Type and Surcharge Amount, so the columns are not fixed. As such, Column B (the first Surcharge Type for any given tracking number) could either be blank OR contain any of a subset of applicable tracking surcharges, with the charge amount associated with that surcharge type being presented in Column C (otherwise it is $0). I want to recreate the data set with my tracking numbers in Column A, all of the possible surcharge types fixed as the column headers (beginning in Column B), and the body of the table containing only the charge amounts, in $, for a given combination of tracking number and surcharge type. 
See current format and desired format as follows.

Current:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waZxh.png)

Desired:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPs6s.png)

How can I most efficiently code this in Excel? 
Now, what if I tell you that a given tracking number can show up more than once in Column A (i.e. adjustments to prior charges). How does this change the formula?

THANK YOU!

Comment: So if I followed your long explanation you could use an if() to run a test vlookup() which if true does another vlookup() or if false does a different vlookup(). Of course you could consider index() with match() instead of vlookup().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula might work:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("<sheetname>!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(<Tracking#>,<sheetname>!$A:$A,0),MATCH(<columnHeader>,INDIRECT("<sheetname>!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(<Tracking#>,<sheetname>!$A:$A,0),2)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(<Tracking#>,<sheetname>!$A:$A,0),<max#ofSurcharges*2+1>)),0)+2)),0)
```

It essentially finds the row of the tracking # on the first sheet and creates an array in which to search for the surcharge name and if it finds the surcharge it will return the value of the adjacent cell, which is the associated value.

Please note that this formula is somewhat dependent on the structure of the raw data: tracking numbers must be in column A and the surcharges need to start in column B.

Also this will only find the first instance of the tracking number in the list, so I suggest adding some form of timestamp to sort your raw data, if you need to use the latest entry.

Edit: a solution using `VLOOKUP` might be more efficient, not sure

Edit2: The problem with `VLOOKUP` is that the raw data is no proper table like the edited data. Really the best solution would be to enter 0 values in the first place, not afterwards.

Anyway, this solution is fairly similar to the above, but uses `VLOOKUP` to retrieve the data in the end. If you are dealing with large sets of data you can test which method is more efficient.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(<Tracking#>,<referenceToRawData>,MATCH(<columnHeader>,INDIRECT("<sheetname>!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(<Tracking#>,<sheetname>!$A:$A,0),2)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(<Tracking#>,<sheetname>!$A:$A,0),<max#ofSurcharges*2+1>)),0)+2,FALSE),0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have gotten the formula to work for my data set. I am looking now to expand to account for duplicates and will update the post with any further questions.